# jQuery seems to run on only one instance

Tags: jquery, html

I need multiple countdown timers for multiple dates on the same page. I want to run the script on all the elements having `class="cd"`. If you check the JSFiddle below, you'll see only one `innerHTML` is set:

https://jsfiddle.net/3924cofL/1/

I managed to get this far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cd").each(function(index, obj) {
    var countDownDate = new Date($(this).attr('value'));
    $id = this.id;

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

      // Get todays date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
      document.getElementById($id).innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
        minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      // If the count down is over, write some text 
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById($id).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="demo" class="cd" value="2018-06-10 18:00:00"></p>
<p id="demo2" class="cd" value="2018-06-11 18:00:00"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just that the `setInterval()` function is an async function.

Which is why if you want to use variables that are outside the function you need to pass them.

**Here is an working example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cd").each(function(index, obj) {
    var countDownDate = new Date($(obj).attr('value'));
    $id = obj.id;

    var x = setInterval(function($id) {
      var now = new Date().getTime();
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      document.getElementById($id).innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
        minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById($id).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000, $id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="demo" class="cd" value="2018-06-10 18:00:00"></p>
<p id="demo2" class="cd" value="2018-06-11 18:00:00"></p>
```

But to be honest there is no reason to do it.

**Why?** Because you get the `id` from an element just to get this element by `id`. That's pointless. It's like I would ask *Hey John, what's your name?*

**Here is a solution** without unnecessary id variable

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cd").each(function(index, obj) {
    var countDownDate = new Date(obj.getAttribute('value'));

    var x = setInterval(function() {
      var now = new Date().getTime();
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      obj.innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
        minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        obj.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="demo" class="cd" value="2018-06-10 18:00:00"></p>
<p id="demo2" class="cd" value="2018-06-11 18:00:00"></p>
```

Comment: This is indeed a better answer than the most voted one.

Answer (score 3):

Your `$id` field is global, so it contains only the last id after the `each()` is finished. You need to change it be a local field:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cd").each(function (index, obj) {
    var countDownDate = new Date($(this).attr('value'));
    var $id = this.id; // <- should be local

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById($id).innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
        + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        // If the count down is over, write some text 
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById($id).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }
    }, 1000);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo" class="cd" value="2018-06-10 18:00:00"></p>
<p id="demo2" class="cd" value="2018-06-11 18:00:00"></p>
```

---

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in other answers, you can also pass the `$id` as a parameter to the `setInterval()`, which is a preferable way, but IE 9 and earlier do not support this syntax. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code as follows:
`$id = this.id;`

with:
`var $id = this.id;`

And voila, it's working

Answer (score 0):

Change your append to, you don't need the ids

```
$(obj).text(days + "d " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
```

demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cd").each(function (index, obj) {
    var countDownDate = new Date($(this).attr('value'));
    var $id = this.id; // <- should be local

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
         $(obj).text(days + "d " + hours + "h "
       + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");

        // If the count down is over, write some text 
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById($id).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }
    }, 1000);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo" class="cd" value="2018-06-10 18:00:00"></p>
<p id="demo2" class="cd" value="2018-06-11 18:00:00"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the $id variable to the setInterval function like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cd").each(function(index, obj) {
    var countDownDate = new Date($(this).attr('value'));
    $id = this.id;

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function(elementId) {

      // Get todays date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
      document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
        minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      // If the count down is over, write some text 
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000, $id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="demo" class="cd" value="2018-06-10 18:00:00"></p>
<p id="demo2" class="cd" value="2018-06-11 18:00:00"></p>
```